# SQL Server 2008 Express - How to update my local database to server database

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-express

I have assigned to update my server database from local database (both running with SQL Server 2008 Express). I have many new data on my local and now I want to move all to server but without changing servers data. Is there any way I can do it automatic?

Comment: I have tried 2 tools, DBComparer and SQLDog. Both are good to compare database schema. SQLDogs compare the data between two db but its not support insert script. 
Im still looking for the tool that can help me to update or insert data which are different  between 2 databases.

Comment: I found the solution using SQL Data Examiner 2012 Demo or dbForge Data Compare for SQL Server tools will provide a way to insert different data between databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can alsouse tools which generate diff scripts, like [this](http://dbcomparer.com/) one for schema or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316705/sql-server-database-compare-tool)

Comment: okay, i will try. i hope they can help me to update server database data from local quickly ^.^